# How can I pass parameters when loading my library in Opencart?

Tags: model-view-controller, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I need to pass parameters to my Opencart library class which is loaded using `$this->load->library('MyLib')`.  The trouble is that the loader only accepts a single argument.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
$this->load->library('MyLib', array('parameters') );
```

How can I pass an array of arguments to my library class when it's loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader's `library()` method only allows a single argument: `$route`, but fortunately `$this->registry` is passed as a single argument to the library's constructor. To pass additional parameters you can simply assign them as properties to the registry class before loading your library like this:

```php
$params = [
    'param_1' => 'abc',
    'param_2' => 'def'
];
$this->registry->set('MyLib_params', $params);

// now load your library
$this->load->library('MyLib');
```

Then, you can access that property inside inside your library constructor like this:

```php
class MyLib {
    public function __constructor($registry) {
        $this->params = $registry->get('MyLib_params');
        // do stuff with $this->params
    }
}
```

Actually, you can access anything in the registry there as well which is useful for getting all kinds of data like config, session, cart, etc.